# How to optimize code duplication, used to check existence of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization, aggregation

This part of code is working, but I want to cut it because **FROM dbo.Ingredients and everything below** I write twice.

```
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 
            dbo.Ingredients
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.Materials 
                ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
                AND dbo.Materials.[Count] > (dbo.Ingredients.[Count] *  @сount)
        WHERE 
            dbo.Ingredients.Product  = @product
    ) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sum DECIMAL(10, 2);
        SET @sum = 0;

        SELECT 
            @sum = SUM(dbo.Materials.[Amount])
        FROM 
            dbo.Ingredients
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.Materials 
                ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
                AND dbo.Materials.[Count] > (dbo.Ingredients.[Count] *  @сount)
        WHERE
            dbo.Ingredients.Product  = @product

        ...

    END
```

I tried to write the logic for calculating the entire amount (@sum) in the IF condition, but I didn’t succeed.

Is it possible to shorten this code?

Comment: If you aliased your objects, and used those for qualifing your columns, your code would be shorter and you'd stop using to be deprecated syntax.

Comment: Why do you even need an `if exists` here at all? Just do the sum and handle it being null  if necessary if no rows are returned `set @sum=isnull(@sum, 0)` or you could union `select 0` into the result set

Comment: Read about VIEWs and Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to use `if exists` here at all, that's just having SQL Server do the same work twice.

Simply run your query and handle the event where no rows are returned.

If you need `@sum` to be zero in the event no rows are returned you can add:

```
set @sum = isnull(@sum, 0);
```

You can use `isnull` in the actual query, but only if you put the whole query inside the `isnull`.

```
declare @sum Decimal(10, 2) = isnull(
(
  select Sum(m.Amount)
  from dbo.Ingredients i
  join dbo.Materials m on i.Material = m.Id
                      and m.[Count] > i.[Count] * @сount
  where i.Product = @product
), 0);
```

Comment: You can put the whole query inside an `isnull` eg `SET @sum = ISNUL((SELECT SUM(Amount) ...), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You need an `IF` statement because you're not sure that the inner join will return you any record, or no record at all.

You can instead remove the `IF` statement and substitute `INNER` with `LEFT`. The side effect of this change is that your query will always return either values or NULL. In order to convert the NULL to something ("0" maybe), you use `COALESCE`.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sum DECIMAL(10, 2);
    SET @sum = 0;

    SELECT @sum = SUM(COALESCE(dbo.Materials.[Amount], 0))
    FROM      dbo.Ingredients
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Materials 
           ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
          AND dbo.Materials.[Count] > (dbo.Ingredients.[Count] *  @сount)
    WHERE dbo.Ingredients.Product  = @product

    ...
END
```